# WSL2 Laravel dusk testing google-chrome driver unable to display site

Tags: php, google-chrome, testing, laravel-8, laravel-dusk

## Laravel Dusk, errors loading google-chrome

I am trying to run tests using Laravel Dusk on a Windows 10 subsystem, WSL2 running Ubuntu. I've followed the installation guides, and I'm stuck at the point after the google-chrome browser is loaded and renders the site:

This is my DuskTestCase.php driver method:

```php
        protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
        ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
            return $items->merge([
                '--disable-gpu',
//                '--headless',
                '--window-size=1920,1080'

            ]);
        })->all());

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        $_ENV['DUSK_DRIVER_URL'] ?? 'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
```

Before running the test, I run chromedriver for linux

```sh
    vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux

returns:
    Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}) on port 9515
```

Next I run any test say AuthTest

```sh
    php artisan dusk tests/Browser/AuthTest.php
```

#### The test cannot render the site: http://localhost:9515

Error in browser:

> {"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"unknown command: unknown command: login","stacktrace":"#0 0x55bf14b857d3 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x55bf148e1688 \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x55bf14932e11 \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x55bf14932b77 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x55bf148b81d4 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x55bf148b9020 \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x55bf14bb649d \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x55bf14bcf60c \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x55bf14bb8205 \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x55bf14bcfee5 \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x55bf14bac070 \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x55bf148b7d49 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x7f7d460390b3 \u003Cunknown>\n"}}

If I load google-chrome manually and try to go to the same address (http://127.0.0.1:9515/), the same error appears.

However if I close everything and run:

````sh
    php artisan serve --port 9515

then
    google-chrome

I am able to manually interact with the site, yet Laravel Dusk cannot load the browser.
The following error is thrown by Laravel Dusk
```bash

    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/simon/sites/acquisitionboardgame_vue/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php o
n line 648
````

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?